# lock pattern possibilities when starting from corner only

Tags: combinatorics

Smartphone lock pattern is a route of length n in a 3x3 grid. In every step it is allowed to move from one point to *any* of the other near points, including in diagonal and including already visited points. Find an explicit expression to the number of patterns of length n *starting from a corner* (find and solve a recursive equation).

What I did: I thought to start from a corner (4 options) and moving to any near point (5 options). So far I've made one move and I'm necessarily in a "non-corner" point. Now if I move back to a "corner point" (4 options) I've made 2 moves so I wrote:
$$f(n)=80\cdot f(n-2)$$

but I don't know how to express the posibility of not going back to a "corner point" in the second move.

edit: one can 5 movees from a given corner cell (3 trivial moves and 2 diagonal moves as can be seen here: [image]

Comment: if you start from a corner, don't you have 3 options (not 5) for the next point?  e.g. from a standard keypad, 1 can go to 2, 4 or 5 (= 3 options)

Comment: yes but in android-like lock pattern you can move also in diagonal. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl1Un.png

Comment: @antkam you can also go to 6 or 8

Comment: @Green oh man i've been mis-using my phone all this time!  :)  Anyway you can recur if you separate the 3 cases.  Let $C_n, E_n, M_n$ be the number of length $n$ patterns starting from **C**orner, **E**dge, **M**iddle respectively, then e.g. $C_{n+1} = 4 E_n + M_n$ and similarly for the other two.  This allows you to compute them but I don't have the skill to convert these 3 simultaneous recurrence equations into closed forms.  (But perhaps can be done with generating functions...?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start out, use a linked recursion . . .

- Let $f(n)$ be the number of paths of length $n$, starting from a corner vertex.$\\[4pt]$

  Let $g(n)$ be the number of paths of length $n$, starting from a non-corner edge vertex.$\\[4pt]$

  Let $h(n)$ be the number of paths of length $n$, starting from the center vetex.

By considering what happens in one move, we get the linked recursion
\begin{align*}
f(n)&=4g(n-1)+h(n-1)\tag{eq1}\\[4pt]
g(n)&=4f(n-1)+2g(n-1)+h(n-1)\tag{eq2}\\[4pt]
h(n)&=4f(n-1)+4g(n-1)\tag{eq3}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
with initial conditions $f(0) = g(0) = h(0) = 1$.

As a sample, here are a few values . . .
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|} 
 n&f(n)&g(n)&h(n)\\ \hline
0&1&1&1\\ \hline
1&5&7&8\\ \hline
2&36&42&48\\ \hline
3&216&276&312\\ \hline
4&1416&1728&1968\\ \hline
5&8880&11088&12576\\ \hline
6&56928&70272&79872\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Next, we unlink the recursion . . .

Assume $n > 1$.

From $(\text{eq}3)$, we get
$$h(n-1) = 4f(n - 2) + 4g(n - 2)\tag{eq4}$$
Using $(\text{eq}4)$ to replace $h(n-1)$ in $(\text{eq}1)$, we get
$$f(n)=4g(n-1)+4f(n-2)+4g(n-2)\tag{eq5}$$
Using $(\text{eq}4)$ to replace $h(n-1)$ in $(\text{eq}2)$, we get
$$g(n)=4f(n-1)+2g(n-1)+ 4f(n-2)+4g(n-2)\tag{eq6}$$
Subtracting $(\text{eq}6)$ from $(\text{eq}5)$, we get
$$f(n)-g(n)=2g(n-1)-4f(n-1)\tag{eq7}$$
From $(\text{eq}5)$, we get
$$f(n+1)=4g(n)+4f(n-1)+4g(n-1)\tag{eq8}$$
Subtracting $(\text{eq}8)$ from twice $(\text{eq}7)$, we get
$$g(n)=-f(n)+{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}f(n+1)-6f(n-1)\tag{eq9}$$
From $(\text{eq}9)$, we get
$$g(n-1)=-f(n-1)+{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}f(n)-6f(n-2)\tag{eq10}$$
Using $(\text{eq}9)$ and $(\text{eq}10)$ to replace $g(n)$ and $g(n-1)$ in $(\text{eq}8)$, and then solving for $f(n+1)$, we get
$$f(n+1)=2f(n)+24f(n-1)+24f(n-2)\tag{eq11}$$
We have $f(0)=1$, and from the linked recursion, we have $f(1)=5$, and $f(2)=36$, hence $f$ satisfies the recurrence
$$
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
1&\text{if}\;n=0\\[4pt]
5&\text{if}\;n=1\\[4pt]
36&\text{if}\;n=2\\[4pt]
2f(n-1)+24f(n-2)+24f(n-3)\;\;\;&\text{if}\;n>2\\
\end{cases}
$$
That's assuming we start from a fixed corner vertex.

If we allow starting from any of the $4$ corner vertices, the answer is just $4f(n)$.

The recurrence for $f$ is a third-order linear recurrence with constant coefficients.

The corresponding characteristic polynomial is
$$x^3-2x^2-24x-24$$
which has $3$ real irrational roots $r,s,t$ with approximate values
\begin{align*}
r&\approx -3.176727981\\[4pt]
s&\approx -1.187158691\\[4pt]
t&\approx 6.363886672\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Then $f(n)$ is equal to
$$f(n)=ar^n+bs^n+ct^n$$
where $a,b,c$ are real irrational numbers with approximate values
$$
\begin{align*}
a&\approx .1349412775\\[4pt]
b&\approx .01012627238\\[4pt]
c&\approx .8549324501\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Love the unlinking!  But the OP asks for 3x3 grid (your phone has 4x4), and, "knight's move" is allowed (see comments to OP).  Great solution for your different phone though.

Comment: Thank you, very informative. Doesn't f(1) should be 20? Because you can pick any corner and make 5 moves each.

Comment: I believe there are 5, talking about a pattern like grid https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl1Un.png

Comment: yes there are, but you can move also in diagonal. see the comments to my initial question. Anyway your solution is a decent base. Yes I'm sure, you are right, I should have done that.

Comment: Can I ask where the problem comes from? Is it from a book? Or a website?

Comment: just an assignment I got in college.

Comment: Was the picture provided to you as part of the assignment?

Comment: no, I found it on MSE. The question I got is exactly the one I posted. I'm just familiar with the lock pattern and know you have 5 moves from each corner (this is not so intuative, I know)

Comment: Ok, I'll revise my answer, but I think you should edit your question to include a link to the image.

Comment: edited my question